# minmax that returns modifiable references

Tags: c++11, generic-programming, rvalue-reference

With all the new features of C++ (C++11 suffices I think), what prevents from having a `std::minmax` function that returns a pair of references.

In this way, if one feeds two modifable references, they can be modified. Is this opening a can of worms?

```
#include<functional>
// maybe all this options can be simplified
template<class T1, class T2> struct common;
template<class T> struct common<T, T>{using type = T;};
template<class T> struct common<T const&, T&>{using type = T const&;};
template<class T> struct common<T&, T const&>{using type = T const&;};
template<class T> struct common<T, T&>{using type = T const&;};
template<class T> struct common<T&, T>{using type = T const&;};
template<class T> struct common<T const&, T>{using type = T const&;};
template<class T> struct common<T, T const&>{using type = T const&;};

template<class T1, class T2, class Compare = std::less<>, class Ret = typename common<T1, T2>::type> 
std::pair<Ret, Ret> minmax(T1&& a, T2&& b, Compare comp = {}){
    return comp(b, a) ? 
        std::pair<Ret, Ret>(std::forward<T2>(b), std::forward<T1>(a))
        : std::pair<Ret, Ret>(std::forward<T1>(a), std::forward<T2>(b));
}
```

Test:

```
#include<cassert>
int main(){
    {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 10;
    auto& small = minmax(a, b).first;
    assert(small == 1);
    small += 1;
    assert(a == 2);
    }{
    int const a = 1;
    int b = 10;
    auto& small = minmax(a, b).first;
    assert(small == 1);
//    small += 1; error small is const reference, because a was const
    }{
    int a = 1;
    int const b = 10;
    auto& small = minmax(a, b).first;
    assert(small == 1);
//    small += 1; error small is const reference, because a was const
    }{
    int const a = 1;
    int const b = 10;
    auto& small = minmax(a, b).first;
    assert(small == 1);
//    small += 1; error small is const reference, because a was const
    }{
    int b = 10;
    auto& small = minmax(int(1), b).first;
    assert(small == 1);
//   small += 1; error small is const reference, because first argument was const
    }{
    int a = 1;
    auto& small = minmax(a, int(10)).first;
    assert(small == 1);
//   small += 1; error small is const reference, because second argument was const
    }
    {
    int const a = 1;
    auto& small = minmax(a, int(10)).first;
    assert(small == 1);
//    small += 1; error small is const reference, because both arguments are const
    }
    {
//    auto& small = minmax(int(1), int(10)).first; // error, not clear why
    auto const& small = minmax(int(1), int(10)).first; // ok
//    auto small2 = minmax(int(1), int(10)).first; // also ok
    assert(small == 1);
//    small += 1; error small is const reference, because both arguments are const
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to put this in a proposal for the C++ committee? Because I think that may be a better audience for such a proposal than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a paper kind of along these lines a long time ago, by [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant): [N2199](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2199.html). Its very opening example demonstrates the precise problem you're trying to solve:

> The function can not be used on the left hand side of an assignment:
>
> ```
> int x = 1;
> int y = 2;
> std::min(x, y) = 3;  // x == 3 desired, currently compile time error
> ```

It goes on to list as examples the frequently dangling reference problem, mixing types, and being useful with move-only types, and goes on to propose new versions of `min` and `max` that address all of these problems - it includes a very thorough implementation at the bottom (which is too long to paste here). Implementing `minmax()` based on that should be pretty straightforward:

```
template <class T, class U,
    class R = typename min_max_return<T&&, U&&>::type>
inline
std::pair<R, R>    
minmax(T&& a, U&& b)
{
    if (b < a)
        return {std::forward<U>(b), std::forward<T>(a)};
    return {std::forward<T>(a), std::forward<U>(b)};
}
```

The paper was rejected at the time. It's possible it could come back though.

Being able to get back mutable references is nice, but being able to avoid *dangling* references is even nicer. Anonymously quoting from an example I saw recently:

> ```
> template<typename T> T sign(T); 
>
> template <typename T> 
> inline auto frob(T x, T y) -> decltype(std::max(sign(x - y), T(0))) { 
>     return std::max(sign(x - y), T(0)); 
> }
> ```
>
> This function has undefined behaviour for all inputs (the narrowest 
>   contract possible?).

Note that your `common` implementation has this problem. These cases:

> ```
> template<class T> struct common<T, T&>{using type = T const&;};
> template<class T> struct common<T&, T>{using type = T const&;};
> template<class T> struct common<T const&, T>{using type = T const&;};
> template<class T> struct common<T, T const&>{using type = T const&;};
> ```

all dangle. What this means if I have:

```
int i = 4;
auto result = your_minmax(i, 5);
```

`result` here is a `pair<int const&, int const&>`, one of which is a reference to `i` and the other of which dangles. All of these cases have to do `using type = T;` in order to be safe.

Comment: Yes, writing the body of the function is not the challenge. The challenge is to write the `common` or `mix_max_result` metafunction and contemplate all the cases. I didn't even consider all the cases and it gets messy very quickly. Do you have an alternative `common` function that will not generate dangling references or is it impossible?

Comment: I think the problem in your last example is a combination of `auto`, which instead of deducing `pair<int const&, int const&> const&` and that `pair<int const&, int const&>` that doesn't let the temporary survive, this is a persistent problem with `const&` members. This last is a serious inconsistency of the language and has been there forever, ultimately leaking into problems like this one.

Comment: @alfC It doesn't matter if it was `pair<T, T> const&` or `pair<T, T>`, the problem is the reference members of the `pair`. There's no problem with `auto` here, and I don't know what "serious inconsistency" you're talking about.

Comment: @alfC Just doing `decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>())` and turning rvalue references into prvalues would get you a lot of the way. But really, Howard's implementation is the right approach.

Comment: the inconsistency in the language is that you can bind a temporary to a const reference and extend the lifetime `double const& d = f();` (`f ` returns a double) and this is good.  But you can not do the same with `pair<double const&, double const&> p = {f(), g()}`, this unfortunately produces a dangling reference. That is the inconsistency.