# Const reference as a member of a class insconsistency

Tags: c++, c++11, const-correctness, dangling-pointer, const-reference

If one creates a const reference to a temporary, its life is extended as if the reference where in the stack.
It is a good feature of the language, although it is presented sometimes like an exception to other rules. 
https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

**However this doesn't work when the const reference is part the member of a class.
Is this an inconsistency of the language?**

Example code:

```
int f(int a){return a + 5;}
int main(){
    int const& b = f(2);
    assert(b == 7); // ok, not a dangling reference

    struct single{
        int const& m_;
        single(int const& m) : m_(m){}
    };
    single s{f(3)};
    assert(s.m_ == 8); // fails, dangling reference

    struct pair{
        int const& m1_;
        int const& m2_;
        pair(int const& m1, int const& m2) : m1_(m1), m2_(m2){}
    };

    pair p{f(3), f(4)};
    assert( p.m1_ == 8 ); // fails, dangling reference
}
```

Is there a workaround for this to work or at least behave more consistently?

I found this to be a limiting factor in a few contexts now. For example, [List using with references, changes behavior when used as a member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788861/list-using-with-references-changes-behavior-when-used-as-a-member) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51878764/225186

---

**EDIT1**: In other answers to similar questions is mentioned that the problem is that the constructor takes a `const&` where the rule doesn't apply.
However a perfect forward still fails. 
In this case, either the inconsistency in the language is more evident or perfect forward is not as perfect.

```
struct single{
    int const& m_;
    template<class T>
    single(T&& m) : m_(std::forward<T>(m)){}
};
```

---

**EDIT2**: Declaring `single const& s{f(3)};` still doesn't help. 
However "moving" the constness to the structure helps.

```
struct single{
    int m_; // no const!
    template<class T>
    single(T&& m) : m_(std::forward<T>(m)){}
};
...
single const& s{f(3)}; // const ref with extended lifetime
```

**So, perhaps it is good practice to transfer the constness to the whole struct.**

I still think that reference members behave weirdly in the language. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYDt1gCDxhM

---

**EDIT3**: As @Oliv mentions, the situation improves if one uses agregate initialization. However this is quite limiting.

```
struct single{
    int const& m_;
};
...
single s{f(3)};
assert(s.m_ == 5);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the duplicate mark does not lead you to the right answer. The language consistency involved is that when a temporary is bound to a reference function argument, the "binding" is released at the end (of the full expression involving) the function call. Constructor call is considered a function call. To avoid that you can use aggregate initialization as described in the first SO answer you cite. Aggregate initialization does not involve binding the temporary to a function reference arguement.

Comment: Second remark, temporary life time expansion is not propagated when you "bind a reference to an other reference."

Comment: A very good answer on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23965233/5632316

Comment: The first duplicate answers the question with a standard quote (the standard explicitly says that constructors don't extend lifetime beyond the constructor call)